# Python Parse List

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a list, not dict, that contains information.  When I simply do `print my_list` it yields:

```
[<Data_1: name=u'Name of A',id=101>,
<Data_2: name=u'Name of B',id=102>,
<Data_3: name=u'Name of C',id=103>,
...]
```

When I do `for x in my_list: print x` it yields:

```
Name of A
Name of B
Name of C
...
```

Clearly Python is parsing this somehow but how would I extract both the name and id portions of each element?  If this was in a dict, I would do `my_list.iteritems` but I am a little stuck on how to do this with just a normal list.

Thanks

Comment: `<Data_1: name=u'Name of A',id=101>` definitely a queryset. So `x.name` and `x.id` should work.

Comment: i can't believe it was that easy.  thanks

Comment: Incidentally, your two pieces of code produce different output because printing an object directly invokes its `__str__` method, whereas printing a list containing objects invokes their `__repr__` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your question would be:

```
for x in my_list: print x.name, x.id
```